# Will vs. Would vs. Be going to

Tags: modal-verbs, will-vs-going-to

I made a conversation based on my understanding of a grammar practice for future tenses. See and correct it please, if I was wrong.

> Togo people A : Hey, wanna see the next match? The one for us against Germany?
>
> Togo people B : Nah... Germany **will win**. :<

40 mins later

> A : Hey, we **are winning**. It's 1:0. Come and watch it together.
>
> B : Sorry, Germany **would win**, no matter what...

2 mins left until it's over. Togo:Germany = 5:2.

> A : You know, we **are going to win** this game.
>
> B : What? Damn, I should have watched it from the beginning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A : Hey, wanna see the next match? The one with us against Germany?
>
> B : Nah... Germany will win.

40 mins later

> A : Hey, we are winning. It's 1:0. Come and watch it with me.
>
> B : Sorry, Germany will win no matter what...

2 mins left until it's over. Togo:Germany = 5:2.

> A : You know, we are going to win this game.
>
> B : What? Damn, I should have watched it from the beginning.

Comment: Thanks. BTW I'm okay with "Germany will win no matter what". But if I use 'would', then would it go completely wrong?

Comment: “Germany would win no matter what” is very definitely wrong, no question about it.